# Is a complex symmetric matrix with positive definite real part diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

Let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a complex-symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. That is, $M$ is equal to its own transpose (without conjugation). If the real part of $M$ is positive-definite, then is $M$ necessarily diagonalizable?

Of course, if we drop the positive-definiteness requirement, then there are examples of non-diagonalizable complex-symmetric matrices. For example,
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is one such example. However, its real part $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is clearly not positive-definite.

Comment: Adding a positive real multiple of the identity will take care of the positive definite condition, but will not affect diagonalisability. See the answer by Om(nom)${}^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Based on your example,
$$
\pmatrix{3&i\\i&1}
$$
will not be diagonalizable, but has a positive definite real part.

Comment: Can't believe this didn't occur to me earlier, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With symmetric matrices I assume people are talking about  $P^T AP$ rather than $Q^{-1} A Q.$ It does appear that the book Horn and Johnson gives some precedence to using the word "diagonalizable" for  $Q^{-1} A Q.$ On page 215, exercise 15 is exactly the example given in the original question.

From Horn and Johnson, on symmetric complex matrices.  Corollary 4.4.4, if complex matrix $A=A^T$ there exists a unitary $U$ and a real nonnegative diagonal $\Sigma$ such that $$A = U \Sigma U^T.$$ This is called [Takagi's factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi.27s_factorization).

I also did the example from the earlier answer by the method I had described, $R^T MR,$ as

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 &\sqrt 3 \\
-1 & \sqrt 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & i \\
i & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 \\
\sqrt 3 & \sqrt 3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
6 + 2i\sqrt 3 & 0 \\
0 & 6 - 2i\sqrt 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: You're right, I should have specified that by "diagonalizable" I mean "similar to a diagonal matrix," i.e., $A = PDP^{-1}$. But this Takagi factorization seems very useful, thanks for sharing!

Comment: One reason to prefer **not** using the term "diagonalizable" for the existence of a complex invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal, is that thus defined is would be _equivalent_ to "symmetric" (in other words the condition is always satisfied in the case you suggest). One can even restrict the diagonal matrix to have diagonal entries $1$ or $0$ only. This is a consequence of the classification of symmetric _blilinear_ forms over$~\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Write this as $M = A + iB,$ where both $A,B$ are real and $A$ is positive definite. It follows that $A$ is invertible. From Horn and Johnson, Theorem 4.5.15, page 228 in the first edition, define $C = A^{-1} B.$ If there is a real invertible matrix $R$ with $R^{-1}CR$ diagonal, there is then a nonsingular real matrix $S$ with $SAS^T$ and $SBS^T$ diagonal. It follows that $SMS^T$ is diagonal complex.

Not sure what happens when $A^{-1}B$ has nontrivial Jordan form.

Comment: Not sure whether this is a yes or no answer.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen people do not typically specify whether they want some $P^{-1}AP$ or some $Q^T AQ$ to be diagonal. When $A$ is real symmetric, the second one is the reasonable choice. More in a few minutes, tea ready.